# Getting internal server error (500) in response after insert/update

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

CRUD operation works fine with the database but i am getting 500 internal server error for POST/PUT operation. I am getting 200 for GET/DELETE.

I worked with crud operation in ASP.NET and my code is running in prod. I have a requirement to migrate that to .NET Core. While testing i found that CRUD operations are working fine and i can see the changes related to data inside the SQL database but for Insert/Update, I am getting 500 error in response.

Code for .NET Framework (Working):-

```
public class ActivityUpdatesController : ApiController
{
    private PortfolioMgmtEntities db = new PortfolioMgmtEntities();

    // GET: api/ActivityUpdates
    public IQueryable<ActivityUpdate> GetActivityUpdates()
    {
        return db.ActivityUpdates;
    }

    [Route("api/activityUpdates/getByProjectId")]       
    public IQueryable<ActivityUpdate> getActivityUpdatesByProjectId(int projectId)
    {
        IQueryable<ActivityUpdate> activityUpdates = from r in db.ActivityUpdates
                                                     where r.ProjectID == projectId
                                   select r;
        return activityUpdates;
    }

    // GET: api/ActivityUpdates/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(ActivityUpdate))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetActivityUpdate(int id)
    {
        ActivityUpdate activityUpdate = db.ActivityUpdates.Find(id);
        if (activityUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(activityUpdate);
    }

    // PUT: api/ActivityUpdates/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutActivityUpdate(int id, ActivityUpdate activityUpdate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != activityUpdate.RecordID)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(activityUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ActivityUpdateExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/ActivityUpdates
    [ResponseType(typeof(ActivityUpdate))]
    [Route("api/activityUpdates/create")]       
    public IHttpActionResult PostActivityUpdate(int projectId, [FromBody] ActivityUpdate activityUpdate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        activityUpdate.ProjectID = projectId;
        activityUpdate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.ActivityUpdates.Add(activityUpdate);
        db.SaveChanges();

        IQueryable<ActivityUpdate> activityUpdates = from au in db.ActivityUpdates
                                        where au.ProjectID == projectId
                                        select au;

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { controller = "ActivityUpdates" }, activityUpdates);
    }

    // DELETE: api/ActivityUpdates/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(ActivityUpdate))]        
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteActivityUpdate(int id)
    {
        ActivityUpdate activityUpdate = db.ActivityUpdates.Find(id);
        if (activityUpdate == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.ActivityUpdates.Remove(activityUpdate);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(activityUpdate);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ActivityUpdateExists(int id)
    {
        return db.ActivityUpdates.Count(e => e.RecordID == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

WebAPiConfig.cs

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"));
    }
```

Code for .NET Core (Not Working):-

```
public class ActivityUpdatesController : Controller
{
    private aeportfoliomgmtdbContext db = new aeportfoliomgmtdbContext();
    // GET: api/ActivityUpdates
    public IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> GetActivityUpdates()
    {
        return db.ActivityUpdates;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/activityUpdates/getByProjectId")]       
    public IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> getActivityUpdatesByProjectId(int projectId)
    {
        IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> activityUpdates = from r in db.ActivityUpdates
                                                     where r.ProjectId == projectId
                                   select r;
        return activityUpdates;
    }



    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/activityUpdates/create")]       
    public IActionResult PostActivityUpdate(int projectId, [FromBody] ActivityUpdates activityUpdate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        activityUpdate.ProjectId = projectId;
        activityUpdate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        db.ActivityUpdates.Add(activityUpdate);
        db.SaveChanges();

        IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> activityUpdates = from au in db.ActivityUpdates
                                        where au.ProjectId == projectId
                                        select au;

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { controller = "ActivityUpdates" }, activityUpdates);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ActivityUpdateExists(int id)
    {
        return db.ActivityUpdates.Count(e => e.RecordId == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                template: "api/{controller}/{id}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: 500 error usually shows some stack trace information/exception detail. Is that not helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion :) I am gettig this error "InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values at at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtRouteResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)". I will check on this and will try to figure out something.

Comment: Your new .net core code doesn't have a controller method for the default get operation on your activity updates. It only has the get by project id one.

Comment: What is the purpose for `return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { controller = "ActivityUpdates" }, activityUpdates);`?  Do you want to return `public IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> getActivityUpdatesByProjectId(int projectId)`?  For `routes.MapRoute(name: "DefaultApi",`, you should not use it as route name in `CreatedAtRoute`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return `GetActivityUpdates` like web api, try to define the route name above the `GetActivityUpdates` method.

```
[HttpGet("api/activityUpdates/GetActivityUpdates", Name = "GetActivityUpdates")]
public IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> GetActivityUpdates()
{
    return db.ActivityUpdates;
}
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/activityUpdates/getByProjectId")]       
public IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> getActivityUpdatesByProjectId(int projectId)
{
    IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> activityUpdates = from r in db.ActivityUpdates
                                                where r.ProjectId == projectId
                            select r;
    return activityUpdates;
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/activityUpdates/create")]       
public IActionResult PostActivityUpdate(int projectId, [FromBody] ActivityUpdates activityUpdate)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    activityUpdate.ProjectId = projectId;
    activityUpdate.UpdatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    db.ActivityUpdates.Add(activityUpdate);
    db.SaveChanges();

    IQueryable<ActivityUpdates> activityUpdates = from au in db.ActivityUpdates
                                    where au.ProjectId == projectId
                                    select au;

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetActivityUpdates", activityUpdates);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try to return Ok() from your post method not created route and check is it working or not. If it is work then may be you does not define the route that you use in created route.

Comment: This is a debugging suggestion, not an answer. It should have been a comment.